# Better way to extract array of objects from Redis on node.js using CoffeeScript

Tags: node.js, redis, coffeescript

Please review the code below and suggest more elegant ways of doing the same.

I am storing JSON strings in Redis database. To extract an array of objects, I use the following code that works. Just for learning though I wanted to find better ways of doing the same. Here is the CoffeeScript code:

```
redis = require "redis"
client = module.exports.client = redis.createClient()

getRecord = module.exports.getRecord = (key, fn) ->
  client.get key, (err, result) ->
    fn err, null if err
    obj = JSON.parse(result)
    fn null, obj

getDataSet = module.exports.getDataSet = (pattern, fn) ->
  client.keys pattern, (err, result) ->
    fn err, null if err
    dataSet = []
    length = result.length
    count = 0
    for key in result
      getRecord key, (err, obj) ->
        fn err, null if err
        count = count + 1
        dataSet.push obj
        fn null, dataSet if count is length
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your code is pretty solid. Just be warned that your

```
for key in result
```

loop is creating a list comprehension; that means that if `result.length` is large, you're going to see significant performance overhead and perhaps even memory issues. To avoid this, you need to add an explicit `return`:

```
for key in result
  getRecord key, (err, obj) ->
    ...
return
```

There was a proposal to introduce a [void function syntax](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/899) for just such cases, but none of CoffeeScript's core committers seem very fond of it.